# Mysql rows to columns

Tags: mysql, rows

I have the following mysql table:

```
+----+-----+-----+--------+
| id | sid | tid |  val   |
+----+-----+-----+--------+
|  1 |   1 |   1 | square |
|  2 |   1 |   2 | big    |
|  3 |   1 |   3 | red    |
|  4 |   2 |   1 | circle |
|  5 |   2 |   2 | small  |
|  6 |   2 |   3 | yellow |
+----+-----+-----+--------+
```

And I would need a query to get the following results:

```
+-----+--------+-------+--------+
| sid | figure | size  | colour |
+-----+--------+-------+--------+
|   1 | square | big   | red    |
|   2 | circle | small | yellow |
+-----+--------+-------+--------+
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the column headers are supposed to be `figure`, `size` and `colour`?  Is that stored _somewhere_ or are you just guessing?

Comment: The column headers don't really matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide any details about how you determine the new column names but based on your data I am guessing that it is based on the values in the `tid` column.  You can use an aggregate function with a case expression to get the result:

```
select 
  sid,
  max(case when tid = 1 then val end) figure,
  max(case when tid = 2 then val end) size,
  max(case when tid = 3 then val end) color
from yourtable
group by sid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/208f46/1)